# Rails tutorial for the dumbest person in the world (me)?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

It is very difficult for me to find Rails tutorials (or books are also great) for my requirements:

1. Stupidity
2. Ruby 1.9 or lastest 1.8
3. MySQL
4. A Game (simple roll play)
5. JQuery front

Thanks you!

Comment: I've always wanted to meet the bastard who made semicolons optional in JavaScript, was that you?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not understanding. :(

Comment: @Nick you mean Brendan Eich? :) I wouldn't call him a bastard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) are great and easy on the eyes too.

Comment: I think this is the best for me in learning the Rails 3.  Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

[Rails for Dummies](http://www.dummies.com/WileyCDA/DummiesTitle/Ruby-on-Rails-For-Dummies.productCd-0470081201.html) is probably your best bet if stupidity is a major issue.

Comment: It is from January 2007 so it is bad place to start learning Rails now. -1

Answer (score 4):

This is a great book: http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails

Comment: I started with Rails mostly because of this book (older edition - but I hope that it's still the same quality)

Comment: Same here, I started with Rails using the third edition. Something I really like about the fourth one is they include testing from the very beginning, making the whole first part of the book a TDD tutorial as well.

Comment: This is my favorite resource. I found learning Rails very difficult at first as well. Also, hire someone to help.

Answer (score 3):

Have you gone through the free, online [RailsTutorial](http://railstutorial.org/book)?

Answer (score 3):

Learn by watching others do it. http://railscasts.com/ or  http://peepcode.com/

Now that that's out of the way, do you really mean to build a **role** playing game using rails ?

Answer (score 1):

I've read and worked through both the Rails Tutorial book and the Agile book and I think the Rails Tutorial book gets you up to speed quicker; it's also more with the times and, as a result, more practical.  There's a lot of info in the Agile book, but a big chunk of it is stuff you can come back to after you're comfortable with Rails.  So I say start with the free Rails Tutorial, watch free screencasts at railscasts.com and at teachmetocode.com, then start building your own projects.

I was going to post links to the books and sites mentioned above but apparently I'm on probation till I get 10 points.